# VS Code Raspberry Pi Pico W C SDK: how to specify inlcudes?

Tags: c, cmake, raspberry-pi-pico

I'm pretty new to Raspberry Pi Pico. I am using Windows 10.

I installed all neccesary stuff (Visual Studio Code, CMake, compiller, etc.) using executable from [here](https://github.com/raspberrypi/pico-setup-windows).

I buit example projects from there, but there was no `pico_w` folder.

I went to https://github.com/raspberrypi/pico-examples and download all example projects, inclunding `pico_w` and just replaced with my current `pico-examples` folder.

I also did the same for SDK (download folder from [GitHub](https://github.com/raspberrypi/pico-sdk) and replace current one with it).

Then I restarted VS Code, switched to "Cmake" extension tab, pressed "Configure All Projects", however there was no `pico_w` element in the list, although in "Explorer" tab, of the project folder, of course it was.

Then I copied `pico_w\wifi\access_point` folder to `hello_world`, just near `serial` and `usb` folders.

After that, it started to be displayed at CMake list, however can't be compiled, becuause it can't find most of include header, such as `pico/cyw43_arch.h`, `lwip/pbuf.h`, `dhcpserver.h`.

Project without that headers sucessfully complies.

What am I doing wrong?

---

I added `"PICO_BOARD": "pico_w"` in `.vscode/setting.json`, now, in `CMakeLists.txt` `PICO_CYW43_SUPPORTED` is true, however, `NOT TARGET pico_cyw43_arch` is also true.

So, what is `TARGET` and how do I make it be `pico_cyw43_arch`?

---

Current CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)

# initialize the SDK directly
include("C:/Program Files/Raspberry Pi/Pico SDK v1.5.1/pico-sdk/pico_sdk_init.cmake")

project(pico_examples C CXX ASM)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

if (PICO_SDK_VERSION_STRING VERSION_LESS "1.3.0")
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Raspberry Pi Pico SDK version 1.3.0 (or later) required. Your version is ${PICO_SDK_VERSION_STRING}")
endif()


# initialize the Raspberry Pi Pico SDK
pico_sdk_init()

include(example_auto_set_url.cmake)

add_compile_options(-Wall
        -Wno-format          # int != int32_t as far as the compiler is concerned because gcc has int32_t as long int
        -Wno-unused-function # we have some for the docs that aren't called
        )
if (CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ID STREQUAL "GNU")
    add_compile_options(-Wno-maybe-uninitialized)
endif()

set(PICO_BOARD pico_w)

# rest of your project
add_subdirectory(pico_w)


add_executable(wifi
    pico_w/wifi/access_point/picow_access_point.c
)

# Add pico_stdlib library which aggregates commonly used features
target_link_libraries(wifi pico_stdlib
pico_cyw43_arch_lwip_poll # we need Wifi to access the GPIO, but we don't need anything else
hardware_flash
hardware_irq
hardware_adc
hardware_pwm
hardware_i2c
hardware_spi
hardware_dma
hardware_exception)

# create map/bin/hex/uf2 file in addition to ELF.
pico_add_extra_outputs(wifi)
```

Current project tree

```
pico_w -> wifi -> access_point    -> dhcpserver -> ...
|       |        |                -> dnsserver -> ...
|       |        |                -> CMakeLists.txt
|       |        |                -> lwipopts.txt
|       |        |                -> picow_access_point.c
|       |        -> CMakeLists.txt
|       |        -> lwipopts_examples_common.h
|        -> CMakeLists.txt
CMakeLists.txt (content above)
exemaple_auto_set_url.cmake
```

Content of `wifi` folder just from GitHub.
Also there is `.vscode` folder, with `setting.json` where I put:

```
{
    "files.associations": {
        "dhcpserver.h": "c"
    },
    "cmake.configureSettings": {
        "PICO_BOARD": "pico_w",
        "TARGET": "access_point",
        "DPICO_CYW43_SUPPORTED": 1
    }
}
```

---

**Update**

Seems, like "submodules" are not initizalied:

```
[cmake]   cyw43-driver submodule has not been initialized; Pico W 
wireless support will be unavailable
[cmake]   hint: try 'git submodule update --init' from your SDK directory
```

What exactly should I do? Just running that command it from cmd or PowerShell does not work

Answer (score 0):

Once you successfully installed CMake, you should just clone the Pico SDK from its GitHub [page](https://github.com/raspberrypi/pico-sdk) and follow the installation procedure as explained in the readme file.

You can also try to replace "pico_w" by "pico" in your CMakeLists.txt: sometimes, dependencies problems can be solved just by doing that.

Once the installation is done, you should have a correct environment to build your project with all the Pico libraries available.

Comment: I found, that in my case `PICO_CYW43_SUPPORTED` variable from `pico_w/CMakeList.txt` is `false`. I do not know why

Comment: @isagsadvb - Does the discovery in your comment above address (solve) your problem?  If so, add that to an answer and close the post.  Even if it doesn[t, that kind of information belongs in your post.  Please edit to add it there.

Comment: @ryyker, no, but I updated my post